# input type="number" is returning string

Tags: php, forms, gettype

when i enter value in input field and submit, gettype() shows that the type of obtained value from input field is a string.But i entered an integer.why?

```
<form method="post" action="ff.php">
              <input type="number" name="tableinteger" /><br />
              <input type="submit" value="submit" />
              </form>
               <?php
               if(isset($_POST['tableinteger'])){
               $num=$_POST['tableinteger'];
               $dt=gettype($num);
               echo $dt;
               if($num<2 || $num>20)
               {
                   print "Enter the number that is between 2 and 20.";
                 }
               else if($dt=="string"){
                echo "Kindly Enter an integer value.";
               }
               else {
               for($i=1; $i<11; $i++)
               {
                   echo $num*$i ."<br />";
               }
               }
             }
          ?>
```

Comment: @sanojlawrence — What other code would you expect?

Comment: cast as int $num= (int)$_POST['tableinteger'];

Comment: I want that if user enter an integer, gettype() should recognize it as an integer and if user enters a string it should recognize it as string without casting

Comment: check my code I have uploaded complete code for your understanding

Comment: @zaidiqbal - you're getting string because of the way data is posted over HTTP; it's not checking the actual contents. If you want to see if you're dealing with an integer, try http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

Comment: I have checked it is_int() is returning false as well.

Answer (score 3):

Because none of the standard encoding methods for form data distinguish between strings and numbers.

Use [`intval`](http://php.net/intval) if you want a integer.

Comment: check my code now i uploaded the complete code now you can understand what i want to do.